# Saving Email Attachments in Specified Folder, File Disappears

Tags: email, outlook, attachment

So I'm trying to make something that takes emails from a specific folder, and saves the attachments in a specific folder. I've taken this code from a previous post and retooled it for my purposes. It runs without error, but it isn't saving the file in the specified folder, and I can't for the life of me figure it out. Can anyone see my errors?

```
Sub ExtractFirstUnreadEmailDetails()
    Dim oOlAp As Object, oOlns As Object, oOlInb As Object
    Dim oOlItm As Object, Br As Object
    Dim oOlAtch As Object
    Dim eSender As String, dtRecvd As String, dtSent As String
    Dim sSubj As String, sMsg As String



'~~> Get Outlook instance
Set oOlAp = GetObject(, "Outlook.application")
Set oOlns = oOlAp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set oOlInb = oOlns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
Set Br = oOlInb.Folders("Brokers")

'~~> Store the relevant info in the variables
For Each oOlItm In oOlInb.Items.Restrict("[UnRead] = True")
    eSender = oOlItm.SenderEmailAddress
    dtRecvd = oOlItm.ReceivedTime
    dtSent = oOlItm.CreationTime
    sSubj = oOlItm.Subject
    sMsg = oOlItm.Body


    Exit For
Next



Const AttachmentPath As String = "C:\Desktop\Test"



'~~> New File Name for the attachment
Dim NewFileName As String
NewFileName = AttachmentPath & Format(Date, "DD-MM-YYYY") & "-"
'NewFileName = oOlItm.Subject & Format(Date, "DD-MM-YYYY") & "-"

'~~> Extract the attachment from the 1st unread email
For Each oOlItm In Br.Items
    For Each oOlAtch In oOlItm.Attachments
            Subject = "Test"
            NewFileName = Subject
            oOlAtch.SaveAsFile NewFileName & oOlAtch.Filename

        Next
    Exit For
Next
End Sub
```

I'd be so appreciative if anyone can point anything out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Picking a path at random is the road to failure.

The file should be saved in a folder named Test you created in C:\Desktop

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub ExtractFirstUnreadEmailDetails()

    ' Set up for Outlook
    '   not for other applications to use Outlook VBA code
    Dim oOlInb As Folder
    Dim Br As Folder

    Dim oOlItm As Object
    Dim oOlAtch As attachment

    Dim Subject As String

    '~~> Get Inbox of Outlook
    Set oOlInb = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

    Set Br = oOlInb.Folders("Brokers")

    Const AttachmentPath As String = "C:\Desktop\Test"

    '~~> New File Name for the attachment
    Dim NewFileName As String

    '~~> Extract the attachment from the 1st unread email
    For Each oOlItm In Br.Items

        For Each oOlAtch In oOlItm.Attachments

            Subject = "Test"

            ' Note the often forgotten path separator
            NewFileName = AttachmentPath & "\" & Subject & Format(Date, "DD-MM-YYYY") & "-" & oOlAtch.fileName

            ' C:\Desktop\Test\Test17-07-2018-fileName
            Debug.Print NewFileName

            oOlAtch.SaveAsFile NewFileName

        Next

        Exit For

    Next

End Sub
```

The result should be a file named: Test17-07-2018-Filename in the folder C:\Desktop\Test

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize I needed that. Worked like a charm! Appreciate it a lot.